# relationship between tables is good approach while table contain big amount of data?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am making an application that interact with database in every 10 second automatically. I want to know that its is good approach to design database with relationship or there is another approach to design database. I am using MySql database.

Comment: Related records is how relational databases work best. Just make very sure you use appropriate data types (and make sure they match - don't store a id field as an integer in one table then try and join against another table that has the id stored in a character field) for your key fields. Make sure you set up appropriate indexes. And VERY important, make sure you normalise you data; do not have a table which has a column of comma separated values used for joining tables.

Comment: Touching MySQL once every 10 seconds is not a problem.  Please describe your use case further.